# Symbol not found: _objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue

Tags: ios, xcode

I was previously able to run my code on an iOS 4.3 device but now I'm getting this error at runtime:

```
 Symbol not found: _objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue
```

The project is using a base sdk of 6.0 and deployment target of 4.0.

Maybe not a coincidence, but this is the first time I've tried to run on this device since upgrading to XCode 4.5.

I've looked in stackoverflow at previous questions containing _objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue but they seem to mention @autoreleasepool, which I'm not using explicitly anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Check that libraries you include are built with the same deployment target requirements as your main project.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not including any libraries (other than standard iOS ones)

Answer (score 1):

The deployment target of your App target should match the deployment target of your project file.